# Convert [object XrayWrapper [object HTMLSpanElement]] to html tag

Tags: javascript, userscripts

In a userscript i am getting `[object XrayWrapper [object HTMLSpanElement]]` instead of html span tag.

How can i get the html tag like `<span>--</span>` from this object?

Comment: Please provide more details on what you're doing and/or trying to do.

Comment: I am printing the dynamically created tags by creating a hook to document.createElement method in userscript. The output is presented in web console using console.log(). This gives `<span<--</span>` in chrome but in firefox the output is shown in `[object XrayWrapper [object HTMLSpanElement]]` object format

Comment: Please [edit] your question to supply that info.

Answer (score 4):

The only difference is in the *toString()* method, which determines what happens when you try to turn an object into a primitive. You didn't state what you want to do, but if you're trying to turn a DOM object into HTML textual representation, then the *outerHTML* property should provide you with what you need.

```
var element = document.createElement("span");
element.appendChild(document.createTextNode("text"));
alert(element.outerHTML); // returns "<span>text</span>"
```

Comment: Can this be done without using document.createElement as i am including this code in the hook created for document.createElement this is becoming a never ending loop. can any one help

Comment: In the above solution where should i add the code which shows [object XrayWrapper [object HTMLSpanElement]]

Comment: This was just an example. Simply refer to `object.outerHTML` instead of `object` in your code.

Comment: object.outerHTML retrieves the tag but how to obtain the innerHTML of the object without creating a new Element. i tried using object.innerHTML but it is showing undefined

Comment: I see. It would appear that the `XrayWrapper` used by Greasemonkey to wrap around `DOM Elements` is quite an imperfect wrapper, since it doesn't really support the `innerHTML` getter/setter. I wrote you a simplistic `innerHTML` implementation, call it like this: `html(element)`. It ignores everything but elements, attributes and text nodes, but it should serve its purpose as long as the `XrayWrapper` supports the other `DOM attributes` I use in the function. http://pastebin.com/9LYPU67r

Answer (score 0):

In the desired html element, just access the innerText property.
ex: `element.innerText`